# Roblox animation only working for the person who created the animtion

Tags: animation, scripting, roblox

Me and my co developer have created roblox scipt for crouching, we have also made multiple animations, however when we press c to run the animation only the person who created the animation can see it. How do i make everyone able to see the animation, and perform it. The script is placed under StarterCharacterSripts. The script runs for everyone tho, when i put print in the functions it prints for everyone.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
if not character or not character.Parent then
    character = player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
end

local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local Animator = humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")

local crouchAnimation = Instance.new("Animation")
crouchAnimation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://00000000000"
local crouchAnimationTrack = humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimation(crouchAnimation)
crouchAnimationTrack.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action
crouchAnimationTrack.Looped = true

local function CheckKeyDown(Key)
    if Key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.C then
        crouchAnimationTrack:Play()
    end
end
local function CheckKeyUp(Key)
    if Key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.C then
        crouchAnimationTrack:Stop()
    end
end

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(CheckKeyDown)
UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(CheckKeyUp)
```

I have tried using my friends animations instead of my own, and then they only work for him.